# как отправлять JavaScript запрос в бинарном режиме на сайт с PHP

Tags: javascript, php

Использую пока JavaScript запрос рабочий такой:

```javascript
let user_name = document . getElementById ( 'login' ) . value ;
localStorage  . setItem ( 'username'  , user_name ) ;
document . getElementById ( 'login' ) . value = "" ;
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest ( ) ;
xhr . open  ( 'POST'  , 'php/checkusername.php'  ) ;
xhr . setRequestHeader  ( "Content-type"  , "application/x-www-form-urlencoded" ) ;
xhr . onload = fun_make_answer ;
let sname = fun_encrypt_username ( user_name ) ;
xhr . send  ( 'name=' + encodeURIComponent ( sname ) ) ;
```

в нём я шифрую имя пользователя и отправляю текстом в `checkusername.php` :

```php
if ( isset ( $_POST['name']) ) {
  $user_name = $_POST ['name'] ;
  # имя юзера зашифровано сессионным входящим паролем
  $user_name  = DecryptUserName ( $user_name ) ;
  $_SESSION [ 'checkusername'  ] = $user_name ;
  ...
```

Никак не могу найти понятные примеры, как делать `send` не текстом, а в бинарном режиме. Бинарный нужен для отправки более длинных сообщений. Так как конвертирование в текст увеличивает размер данных в два раза.
Показывают везде то `json` , то `FormData`. Какой способ использовать и как? *желательно с минимальными исправлениями кода*

Comment: **Комментарии были [перемещены в чат](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/144461/discussion-on-question-by-alexglebe---javascript---); пожалуйста, не продолжайте дискуссию здесь.** Прежде чем разместить комментарий ниже этого, пожалуйста, ознакомьтесь с [назначением комментариев](/help/privileges/comment). Комментарии, которые не запрашивают уточнения или не предлагают улучшения, скорее всего должны быть [ответами](/help/how-to-answer), размещены на [meta] или написаны в [chat]. Комментарии, продолжающие дискуссию, могут быть удалены.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для отправки бинарных данных в XMLHttpRequest берём объект FormData (не претендую на работоспособность! Не проверяю!):

```
let user_name = document.getElementById('login').value;
localStorage.setItem('username', user_name);
document.getElementById('login').value = "";
let xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open('POST', 'php/checkusername.php');
xhr.onload = fun_make_answer;
let data = new FormData();
let sname = fun_encrypt_username(user_name);
data.append('name', sname);
xhr.send(data);
```

Comment: американский ответ проверял и не работал *в чате про это говорил*, приходило `$_POST ['name'] = '169,35,..` а сейчас всё пучком. `$_POST ['name']='hDXjH1jp5T+\r\n' 0.enter_session_password='f8pnmgBC2INX25yRfwOye16ci8rQ2eMLGeM97NLvC5RdjdrMPF' 1.$user_name='alex'` *какая-то мелочь зараза попалась.*